# What to do with the question with an opened bounty which was radically changed after being answered?

Tags: discussion, bounty

The author of [this recent question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/274609/6605), after receiving a valid answer, completely rewrote his question, invalidating the answer. The author also opened a bounty.

What should be done with such questions?

Should they be closed? If yes, why?

Or flagged?

Or simply downvoted?

Or reverted to its original stage?

I imagine that the question should be reverted through the rollback to its initial form, without being closed, flagged or downvoted. But given the presence of a bounty, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to chip in here as the question OP.

My actions were thought out, and intentions were sincere for the better choice for Stack and users.
I also understand your raising this Meta question. These things need to be discussed (i.e. no sour grapes...)

### Raise a new question

I saw no need to raise a new question as the topic and basic premise of both new and previous question data are the same.

Raising a new question would likely have been a dupe, and I wouldn't have been well received from users seeing I previously asked the same thing (as I dislike when others do).

The fact I edited *the entire text* does not automatically mean I changed the question, topic, or scope.
In essence all I did was reword, which produced the same question.

### An answer already exists

MainMa wrote:

> after receiving a valid answer

It is arguably not that valid (I only upvoted for the thanks for the info and an additional option I had not thought of).

The answer doesn't really take into consideration my concern (in my original question text) about *injecting all data into the global space*.

That said, I had no issue with the answer, I was grateful *Ixrec* provided new food for thought, and why I upvoted.

As the question is the same, the answer is still as valid a suggestion as it was prior to the edit.

### Better question in the first place

You could argue why not make this "better question" in the first place.

I took 40 mins or so to write the original question, and thought it to be well written.
However, one cannot predict everything, and the *feedback* from 2 days with 44 views and no results, prompted me to believe, in addition to a bounty, my question could perhaps do with improvement as well.

On that concern, how does one define what size of edit is a *legitimate* edit, and what is too much?
I would have thought logically, and based on Stack's structure, if the edit does not change the scope of the question, then it is fine.

### What should I have done?

MainMa wrote:

> I imagine that the question should be reverted through the rollback to its initial form, without being closed, flagged or downvoted.

What could I have done?

Had I created a new question, it would have been the same question asked in different words - and in Stack that is a dupe.

If my new text would have been a dupe, then they must be (arguably) "the same", and so the edit acceptable.

I could have just added the bounty, but that isn't ideal really, nor do I see any problem with me improving my question as it remained the same question, and avoided a dupe.

---

In summary, I believe I caused no issue.

However, I am sincerely ok if community (or mod) decides this should be reverted.

I'll be left stuck, however, as copying the new text to a new answer will be a dupe of my current one.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. In general, edits which invalidate previous answers are not welcome, but your answer here, I think, shows that your edit is perfectly valid.

Comment: This does explain a lot; I had no idea that creating globals was the main concern when I wrote my answer. Your original version looked to me like "this config object in my code feels awkward, where else can I put it?" And when I first saw the edited version, the sheer scope of the rewrite made me go "Nope, not touching this question anymore." almost instantly. I'm still not convinced they would have been considered duplicates, but my contribution being invalidated isn't a big deal (it's not exactly a mind-blowing answer), and the new question is definitely more interesting.

Comment: @Ixrec / MainMa Yeah sorry about any confusion. It's hard to explain what I want/have etc, given it's probably a dev design choice which should be made by knowing the rest of the setup, which cannot be outlined in a question without a gazillion words.